# How to implement the authentication system using emberjs and rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ember.js

I'm building a app using emberjs and active_model_serializer.

I searched a lot to find out on how to implement the authentication/authorization with emberjs and rails, but couldn't.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 3):

I am currently working on this kind of topic: I am using Devise, and have tried two kind of solutions:

1. Either use navigation for auth, delegating the whole process to Devise's standard controllers & views,
2. Or you can wrap Devise's controllers to return JSON to a pure single
   page application.

I tried both and all is working well. To inconvenient with #1 is the 'old fashioned' blink at auth navigation. Solution #2 has my preference.

Here is an example of Devise auth wrapping in JSON:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    render(json: resource, status: :ok) and return
  end

  ...
```

The point that is still annoying me is that I had to *completely* override controller method, to avoid double rendering, as Devise is not yet designed to have customizable rendering.

Comment: do you want leave a brief code  example of option 2 to make your answer much clearer. @Millisami if you have solved this, do you mind updating your question with your answer. Thanks.